# java progem to find distributional array of a word

Tags: java, word-frequency

I want to find the frequency of a word in each line of a file. I want to do this for every word in the file. I'm using BufferedReader and FileReader in java.

Comment: You need to state some real question, tell what you have tried, why it does not work.

Comment: it smells like homework, you need to show your efforts

Comment: "can anyone help me plz???"  Can you support that you are not a clueless teenager by spelling words properly and using a single upper case letter at the start of every sentence?  Also, please fix that sticky '?' key.  One '?' indicates a question, while 2 or more typically indicates a moron.

Comment: With all these negative comments it gets an upvote! Yeah, welcome to SO

Answer (score 2):

I recommend two things:

1) break down your question better.
Are you trying to find the frequency of words in each line? Or the frequency of words in the file. As in, if your input was :

```
test test dog cat dog dog cat
test cat dog dog cat test
```

Would you want:

```
test: 2, 1
dog: 3, 2
cat: 2, 2
```

Or would you want

```
test: 3
dog: 5
cat: 4
```

2) here's the tools you need

```
Map<String,Integer> wordCounts; // store your word counts in your class

/**
 * countWord- a method to signify counting a word
 * @param word the word just counted
 */   
public void countWord(String word) {
    int counts = 0; // assume it does not exist yet
    if(wordCounts.containsKey(word)) { // but if it does, get that count
        counts = wordCounts.get(word);
    } /* end if(contains(word))*/
    wordCounts.put(word,counts + 1); // tell the map to put one more than there was
} /* end countWord */
```